# SAS if-else if not working

Tags: sas

[combd dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3Lka.png)

SAS is checking the first if statement and ignoring the others for some reason. For a couple obs "class" = 1 and for all the others it is blank. What do I do? I do need the parentheses to group those "or" statements right. Attached is the combd dataset. Just noticed for obs where SAS has class=1 it is wrong!

```
data clustered;
set combd;
 if ((393821 ge avpm le 450041) or (337601 ge avpm le 393821) or (225161  
  ge avpm le 281381)) and (.8768 ge fsp le 1) then class='1';
   else if ((112720 ge avpm le 168940) or (56500 ge avpm le 112720) or  
    (280.06 ge avpm le 56500)) and (.8768 ge fsp le 1) then class='2';
     else if (280.06 ge avpm le 56500) and ((.507 ge fsp le .6303) or 
      (.3838 ge fsp le .507) or (.2606 ge fsp le .3838)) then class='3';
        else if (280.06 ge avpm le 56500) and ((.1373 ge fsp le .2606) or 
         (.0141 ge fsp le .1373)) then class='4';
          else if (280.06 ge avpm le 56500) and (.8768 ge fsp le 1) then  
           class='5';
            else if (280.06 ge avpm le 56500) and ((.8768 ge fsp le 1) or 
             (.7535 ge fsp le .8768) or (.6303 ge fsp le .7535)) then 
              class='6';
               run;
```

Comment: There must be a reason for none of the `else if` conditions to be true. I don't think anyone can tell you why without an input sample.

Comment: Ok Petr. So you're pretty confident there is nothing wrong with the code as I have it written?

Comment: I don't see any syntax issue there. The first thing I would try now is checking the input data vs. remaining `else if` conditions. Alternatively, you can post a data sample.

Comment: Ok. Data uploaded.

Comment: Please insert data as *text*; pictures have no place in questions on StackOverflow unless you're asking about graphics or interface (and thus the picture is part of the question), or are asking about functionality of a piece of software you're using.  Datalines (like I show in my answer) is the preferred way to show it in [tag:sas].

Comment: I was wrong assuming the data input is needed. Joe is right :)

Comment: Data input is also helpful of course, and expected for any question like this.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
(393821 ge avpm le 450041)
```

Any number less than 393821 will also be less than 450041.

You want this:

```
(393821 le avpm le 450041)
```

393821 less than AVPM less than 450041, meaning, avpm is between 393821 and 450041.  Do that for all of your data.

Second: don't write your code this way.  It's hard to read and difficult to debug.  Instead use a data driven code method.

You have really a relationship here, right?  [some AVPM values] and [some FSP values] -> [some CLASS value]

So let's make a table:

```
data class;
input class avpm_min avpm_max fsp_min fsp_max;
datalines;
1 393821 450041 .8768 1
1 337601 393821 .8768 1
1 225161 281381 .8768 1
2 112720 168940 .8768 1
2 056500 112720 .8768 1
2 280.06 056500 .8768 1
3 280.06 056500 .5070 .6303
3 280.06 056500 .3838 .5070
3 280.06 056500 .2606 .3838
6 280.06 056500 .6303 .7535
6 280.06 056500 .7535 .8768
;;;; /*more datalines of course */
run;
```

And then let's use `PROC SQL` to join this to the main table.

```
data your_data;
input avpm fsp;
obs=_n_;
datalines;
13026.14 .81888
1810.57 .84959
3859.84 .85593
3290.61 .57513
10704.72 .71414
;;;;
run;

proc sql;
  select d.obs, d.avpm, d.fsp, c.class from
    your_data d
    left join class c
    on c.avpm_min le d.avpm le c.avpm_max
    and c.fsp_min le d.fsp  le c.fsp_max
    order by d.obs
    ;
quit;
```

There you go.

I'd also note that your IF/ELSE combinations don't really make sense for 4/5/6. 5 is impossible (it's entirely subsumed by 2) and part of 6 is also.

Comment: I'd also note that odds are, you *already* have a table like `class`: you probably made those class values through some sort of clustering proc, or something like that, right?  So you probably didn't need to do any of this.  Just use that table directly (`ods output` to make it a table if you don't have an `out` option on the proc that made it).

Comment: I'm not following you Joe. "Any number less than 450041 will also be less than 393821."  450000 is less than 450041 but not less than 393821. What am I missing?

Comment: The bounds for the clusters are from enterprise miner 14.1 and it gives no table.

Comment: Sorry, I reversed those two.  Any number less than 393821 will be less than 450041.

Comment: And I'm fairly confident EMiner allows output of datasets, though I don't use it so I can't tell you how. But not only does SAS typically allow some form of output, a quick google search shows lots of hits for this.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Joe. That way for coding bounds is counter-intuitive but it works.

Comment: In EM look at the properties pane and it will have a section with output dataset and you can find the name and location of the output of the data. I personally don’t like to do any data management within EM.